# Jsonb_object_keys() does not return any rows in left join if the right side table does not have any matching records

Tags: postgresql

This is db query .

```
select users.Id,jsonb_object_keys(orders.metadata::jsonb) from users left join orders on users.userId=orders.userId where users.userId=2;
```

```
users table                 orders table
------------------- -----------------------------------------------------
|userId| name     | | userId|orderId|metadata                           |
| 1    | john     | |  1    | 1     | {"orderName":"chess","quantity":1}|
| 2    | doe      | |  1    | 2     | {"orderName":"cube" ,"quantity":1}|
------------------- -----------------------------------------------------
```

Why there are no rows returned by the query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Nice and tricky question. to achieve what you want you should try below query:

```
select
t1.userid,
t2.keys
from 
users  t1 
left join (select userid, orderid, jsonb_object_keys(metadata) as keys from orders) t2
on t1.userid=t2.userid
```

Your Query seems correct but there is catch. When you are left joining both tables without `jsonb_object_keys(metadata)`, it will work as you are expecting. But when you use with this function then this function will return a `set of records` for each rows of select statement and perform simple join with rest of the columns internally. That's why it will remove the rows having `NULL` value in second column.

Answer (score 1):

You should left join to the result of the jsonb_each() call:

```
select users.userid, meta.*
from users 
  left join orders on users.userid = orders.userid 
  left join jsonb_object_keys(orders.metadata::jsonb) as meta on true
where users.userid = 2;
```